# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, docker

> Unhandled exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

This is a NET5.0 console app using dapper to execute a stored procedure that will not store a result. The app is running from a linux docker container (Docker Desktop - Windows). The error happens each time a new container is created, and run for this first time. If the container is run again, the error will not occur.

```
using(IDbConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Server=my-azure-managed-instance.database.windows.net;Database=MyDB;User Id=me;Password=pw;")
{
    sc.Execute("usp_MyProcedure", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Does anyone know what situations might end up with "(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)" as an error message?

Comment: Please [edit] and add your connection string (obfuscated if necessary) and explain the network connection between you and the server.

Comment: Good point! Context helps...edited

Comment: Have you opened up the Azure firewall and allowed remote connections? If this user is not a `sysadmin` have you given correct `CONNECT SQL` and `dbdatareader` permissions

Comment: Perms look good. Seems to be okay since it runs no issue if we rerun the container. It is only trouble on the first container run lol. Side note - This is running from Docker Desktop. Going to throw it in K8s & see if it still happens

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am getting the same issue running in Docker Desktop.

Comment: No I did not :(